# Can't upload big multimedia items with WordPress rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, wordpress-rest-api

I have this code as a script, it uploads pics or videos flawlessly to WP media library.

```
<?php



$archivo = "/var/www/Digital_Signage/formulario/".$_GET["ruta"]; // Guardamos la ruta en la variable archivo
$username = 'gpda';   //usuario
$password = 'Pvry ZQ3N uypF 1AY6 876h yC8B'; // contraseña

$curl = curl_init(); //Inicia una nueva sesión del curl
$data = file_get_contents( $archivo );

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( // Dentro del curl_setopt se definen las opciones para nuestra sesión
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://10.124.133.1:8182/wp-json/wp/v2/media/", //Define la URL de la petición HTTP
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //Muestra el resultado del proceso (El contenido que devuelve la página se almacene en una variable)
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", //se enviarán todos los tipos de condificación soportados
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, //Número máximo de redirecciones HTTP a seguir.
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, //Número máximo de segundos permitido para ejectuar funciones cURL
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, // Versión HTTP
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", // Método de petición
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( //Array de campos a configurar para el header HTTP
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($archivo).'"',
  ),
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
));

//Redireccionamos a peticiones.php
header('Location: peticiones.php');

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "No se ha podido insertar en la galeria de medios de Wordpress!" . $err;
} else {
  echo "Exito se ha insertado en la galeria de medios de Wordpress!".  $response;
}


?>
~
```

The problem comes when I try to upload multimedia bigger than 8Mb, I already set **maximum_upload_file_size** to **+2000M** as you can see here:

[image]

However, when I try to upload a video of 130Mb the script just gets stuck and does not work, any fix around?

Comment: Check the webserver settings as well - it has its own settings for maximum body size (and comes _before_ PHP to reject the request)

Comment: check the post_maxsize, and upload_size settings in the php.ini file over the server, they need to be increased, in terms of uploading big-size files. Also, make sure to restart the apache server once the settings get updated.

Comment: I have Apache as webserver how can I edit maximum body size?

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed it. 
I only had to set this on my PHP script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');
```

Then I entered these values in ***wp-config.php*** which is located inside the WordPress folder (I'm currently running WP with a Docker)

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '2000M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '2000M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '2000M' );
```

Now restart Apache, PHP and the WP docker and everything is working fine :)